# Setting a default program by command prompt

Tags: windows, prompt

Is it possible to set the default program to open a  specific file from the  Windows command prompt?

Comment: Sure, use `reg.exe` to modify the Registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try to create a linking point:

> Rightclick on the Desktop
>
> Choose create a linking point
>
> Choose cmd.exe from c:windows/system32
>
> Click okay
>
> Right click on the linking point
>
> In the destination window add to C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe what do you want ...
>
> E.g. -cmd /K  cd / & help

or

> E.g. -cmd /K more someTextFile.txt